# mat-form-field always show required red color?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Is there any way to always show the red color of a `mat-form-field` when it have the `required="true"`, even if I never set the focus on it or I touched it?

```
<mat-form-field color="accent">
  <input matInput placeholder="ID is required" required="true [(ngModel)]="uniqueID">
</mat-form-field>
```

I just want to show the red color of the error but from the beginning, before I even touch the input.

How Is it posible?

Comment: share your html code

Comment: @SunilSingh I just update the question

Comment: Initial observation. double quote missing after required true.

Comment: You don't have to set the required attribute to `true`.

Comment: You could also use a custom `ErrorStateMatcher`: https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown

Comment: Please see revision to my answer to include a template driven scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use reactive forms... using `ngAfterViewInit`, you could programmatically mark the field as touched to force the error.

- Unfortunately I am not familiar with how to accomplish this via
  template driven forms.

  ```
  setTimeout(() => {
          this.yourForm.controls['yourControl'].markAsTouched();
        }, 0);
  ```

**Revision**

Based on my original answer, and the expansion of my answer by Abhishek to re-enforce that you can do this with reactive forms... I wanted to provide the template driven form scenario as well.

- The common theme here, regardless if you use reactive forms or template driven forms is that, you need to programmatically mark the
  input as touched...
- In template driven forms you will also need to do
  the same via template reference so that you can call the markAsTouched() method on the control in
  your ngOnInit life cycle hook.

Set a template reference of id and bind it to ngModel via `#id="ngModel"` on the input... you will also need to assign a name on the input of id via `name="id"` this is a requirement of binding to ngModel.

```
<mat-form-field color="accent">
    <input matInput placeholder="ID is required" required="true" [(ngModel)]="uniqueID" name="id" #id="ngModel">
</mat-form-field>

<div *ngIf="id.invalid && (id.dirty || id.touched)">
    <mat-error *ngIf="id.errors.required">
        ID is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
</div>

<pre>id.errors: {{id.errors | json}}</pre>
```

From here you will need to use `@ViewChild` in your component to get reference to `#id` and call `markAsTouched()` on the control via ngOnInit life cycle hook.

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('id') _id : any

ngOnInit(){
  this._id.control.markAsTouched();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following demo shows the required case in an existing angular material reactive form.

**Application Demo :** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-reactive-form-2rksrw?file=app/app.component.ts

**Approach :**

- In `ngOnInit`, we can get the input element from the form and can modify as 
   `this.formGroup.get('name').markAsTouched();`
- We can also exploit the `touched` property of the from input as 
   `this.formGroup.get('name').touched = true;`, but this will generate an error `Cannot assign to 'touched' because it is a constant or a read-only property`.
   But in the stackblitz demo, you can see it working as we can see the difference with `this.formGroup.get('name').touched = false;` also.

The `formGroup` is created in following manner in the demo form :

```
 this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      'email': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(emailregex)]],
      'name': [null, Validators.required],
      'password': [null, [Validators.required, this.checkPassword]],
      'description': [null, [Validators.required]],
      'validate': ''
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
   <mat-form-field class="floatRight"> <input matInput [formControl]="formfieldControl" placeholder="enter name"[(ngModel)]="strSolrCoreName" Required> 
   </mat-form-field>
```

**.ts File**

```
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class abc{
formfieldControl = new FormControl( '', [Validators.required] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Update:***

Since `[(ngModel)]` is deprecated like Marshal mentioned, you can remove `[(ngModel)]` and use the built-in Observable `valueChanges` of `FormControl` to get user input as follows:

.html

```
<mat-form-field color="accent">
  <input matInput placeholder="ID is required" required [formControl]="formFieldControl">
</mat-form-field>
```

.ts

```
formFieldControl: FormControl;

ngOnInit() {
  formFieldControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  this.formFieldControl.markAsTouched();
  this.formFieldControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value
      uniqueID = value;
    );
}
```

***Original Answer:***

The simplest solution is in the answer of Abhishek Kumar. Here is all you need in your example:

.html

```
<mat-form-field color="accent">
  <input matInput placeholder="ID is required" required [formControl]="formFieldControl" [(ngModel)]="uniqueID">
</mat-form-field>
```

.ts

```
formFieldControl: FormControl;

ngOnInit() {
  this.formFieldControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  this.formFieldControl.markAsTouched();
}
```

Comment: You are using `formControl` with `ngModel`, which is deprecated and will be removed. Be careful here as this will break eventually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom mat-label similar to the example in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/examples).

[Stackblitz for the example in docs](https://stackblitz.com/angular/yvoyadxyrlb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-label-example.html)

**Template code:**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>ID is required<span style="color: red">&nbsp;*</span></mat-label>
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="uniqueID">
</mat-form-field>
```

Since we are showing the * through the mat-label, putting the `required` attribute on the input will put an additional * on the field, so it should be omitted. You can handle validation in the component.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set conditional label color or class when value is not provided.

**html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label [style.color]='!value ? "red" : "inherit"'>Label</mat-label>
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]='value' required>
</mat-form-field>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fzavy6?file=src/app/form-field-label-example.html)

If you want to use class:

**html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label [class.required]='!value'>Label</mat-label>
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]='value' required>
</mat-form-field>
```

**css (scss)**

```
.required {
    color: red;
    // color: mat-color($warn, 500);
  }
```